# Order table numerically and get the list number

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

In my WordPress site, I have a custom user metadata `reputation`. The value is numeric and is used similarly to how points/reputations are used here at Stackoverflow.

I want to `get` the number of which the user ranks to others.

Browsing the database, all I need to do is to list the table in a descending order and I can see who is ranked at 1 (has most points) and so on...

**Is there any way I can show the rank number to the user?** I am guessing the best way is to order the table in descending order, and somehow get the number of where the user is placed in that list?

I want to GET the user's rank number. Similar to the function below that get the user's total comment count. I need user_id to be the argument:

```
function get_user_comments_count( $uid ){
    global $wpdb;
    $where = 'WHERE comment_approved = 1 AND user_id = ' . $uid ;
    $comment_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total 
                FROM {$wpdb->comments}
                {$where}");
    return $comment_count;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a single key `reputation` per user or there can be multiple keys `reputation` per user  ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Single. Just a string added to the user's metadata via update_user_meta(): http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use join for your user table and meta data and order by the meta_value stored in column,

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM `wp_users` u
JOIN `wp_usermeta` um ON(u.ID = um.`user_id`)
WHERE um.`meta_key` = 'reputation'
ORDER BY um.`meta_value` * 1 DESC
```

Using `* 1` in order is a simple casting trick to integer and desc will list the user by their reputation score so the user with higher reputation will be listed first and so on

---

```
global $wpdb;
$query="    SELECT u.*,um.`meta_value` as `rank` 
    FROM $wpdb->users u
    JOIN $wpdb->usermeta um ON(u.ID = um.`user_id`)
    WHERE um.`meta_key` = 'reputation'
    ORDER BY um.`meta_value` * 1 DESC";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT );
```

Loop through your results

```
foreach($results as $r){
echo $r->rank; // rank of user
}
```

---

**Edit from comments**

here is your function

```
function getReputationByUser($user_id){
    if(!is_numeric($user_id)){
    return false;
    }
    global $wpdb;
    $query="    SELECT um.`meta_value` as `rank`
        FROM  $wpdb->usermeta um
        WHERE um.`meta_key` = 'reputation'
        AND um.user_id = '".$user_id."'
        ";
    $result  = $wpdb->get_row($query);
    if(!empty($result)){
    return $result->rank;
    }
    return false;
}

echo getReputationByUser(100);
```

---

Above code is for returning the reputation if you want the rank of user based on reputation you can get this by below query but i am not sure if you can use `@variables` of Mysql in `WPDB` class

```
SELECT t1.`rank`
FROM(
SELECT 
  um.user_id,
  @rownum:= @rownum + 1 `rank` 
FROM
  wp_usermeta um 
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) t 
WHERE um.`meta_key` = 'reputation' 
ORDER BY um.`meta_value` * 1 DESC 
) t1
WHERE t1.user_id = 100
```

function for above query

```
function getReputationByUser($user_id){
        if(!is_numeric($user_id)){
        return false;
        }
        global $wpdb;
        $query=" SELECT t1.`rank`
        FROM(
        SELECT
          um.user_id,
          @rownum:= @rownum + 1 `rank`
        FROM
          $wpdb->usermeta um
          CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) t
        WHERE um.`meta_key` = 'reputation'
        ORDER BY um.`meta_value` * 1 DESC
        ) t1
        WHERE t1.user_id = '".$user_id."'";
        $result  = $wpdb->get_row($query);
        if(!empty($result)){
        return $result->rank;
        }
        return false;
}

echo getReputationByUser(100);
```

---

Here is another way to find the rank for user using `group_concat` and `find_in_set` functions

```
SELECT user_id,FIND_IN_SET(
              user_id,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( user_id ORDER BY meta_value * 1 DESC)  
                      FROM `wp_usermeta` 
                      WHERE meta_key ='reputation')
                   ) AS rank
FROM wp_usermeta
WHERE meta_key ='reputation'
AND user_id = 100

function getReputationByUser($user_id){
        if(!is_numeric($user_id)){
        return false;
        }
        global $wpdb;
        $query="SELECT user_id,FIND_IN_SET(
                      user_id,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( user_id ORDER BY meta_value * 1 DESC)
                              FROM $wpdb->usermeta
                              WHERE meta_key ='reputation')
                           ) AS rank
        FROM $wpdb->usermeta
        WHERE meta_key ='reputation'
        AND user_id = '".$user_id."'
        ";
        $result  = $wpdb->get_row($query);
        if(!empty($result)){
        return $result->rank;
        }
        return false;
}

echo getReputationByUser(100);
```

---

- [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

> According to docs The result is truncated to the maximum length that
>   is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a
>   default value of 1024. The value can be set higher, although the
>   effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the
>   value of max_allowed_packet.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate how I would do this using wpdb: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: Note that my aim is to **get** the rank number.

Comment: @GaryWoods see my updated answer in loop you can get the rank of user i.e their reputation in `$r->rank`

Comment: This is a great answer. I have on final request. Please see my updated question. Can you please put it in a function with $user_id as the argument? So the function returns the user's rank?

Comment: @GaryWoods i have updated my answer for the function to return reputation for user

Comment: Just tested the function in my production site. Blank page. Unfortunately we have errors disabled. Can you find what is wrong in your code? Very likely a typo somewhere?

Comment: Ah, ran it locally, found: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '(' -- Is it related to the if(!empty) line?

Comment: @GaryWoods that was a typo in my answer `!empty($result)` fixed it now

Comment: Thank you. I will bounty this question for 50 points because you are putting a lot of work into it. I tested the code but unfortunately, nothing is echoed. Is there something wrong with your query? Just to clarify again. I have a custom user metadata 'reputation'. It simply contains a number. I want to find out how users rank to each other. So for example, the top user has 5000 reputation value. If I would add the $user_id of this user through your function, it should return '1'. Because this user is the top ranked user. Does this make sense?

Comment: @GaryWoods if you want the rank based on user reputation you can see the last edit in my answer n i don't guess why above code is not working for you i will look for the solution after some time

Comment: Can you please put your updated code into a function so that I can run it and confirm if it works? Like the getReputationByUser() function.

Comment: @GaryWoods i have tried this code in header.php of theme it works also there was a typo in `is_numeric()` too try now :)

Comment: The first getReputationByUser() works fine, the one that simply returns the users reputation. But, the latest one, rank based on reputation, is not working, and this is the one that I need. Can you please test it and see why it is not working?

Comment: @GaryWoods this was my last update for the answer please see group_concat and find_in_set functions part of answer

Comment: Oh man, this is awesome, thank you so much. I will award you bounty in two days when this question is eligible for one. You have no idea how much work you just saved me!!

Comment: Thanks again, here is your bounty.